# Scrolling window to the bottom of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I am trying to add a functionality to a module in the application am working on, which will scroll the browser window to the bottom of an element when the element height is greater than the window's height.

the module is kinda similar to the snippet below, when you add an item to the list when the list's height is greater than the window's height you would have to scroll down to see the add button again, so is there a way i can do this automatically, by the way == (BTW) i don't mean scrolling to the bottom of the document, just a specific element.

```js
(function() {

  var lists = document.querySelector('ul'),
    addBtn = lists.nextElementSibling.lastElementChild,
    textInput = addBtn.previousElementSibling;

  addBtn.addEventListener('click', appendItem);

  function appendItem() {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    if (textInput.value == '') item.innerText = 'test-item';
    else item.innerText = textInput.value;

    lists.appendChild(item);
  }

  console.log(lists, addBtn, textInput);
})();
```

```css
div:not(#fake-form) {
  background-color: #F9F2C4;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}
div#fake-form {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
}
input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>test item</li>
    <li>test item</li>
    <li>test item</li>
    <li>test item</li>
    <li>test item</li>
    <li>test item</li>
    <li>test item</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="fake-form">
    <input type="text">
    <button>add item</button>
  </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jQuery code will scroll to put the bottom of the element at the bottom of the window. I basically just get the top position of the element to scroll to, then add the height of the element to the top position to determine the bottom position. Subtracting the window height from the bottom position value, then scrolling to the resulting value will put the bottom of the element at the bottom of the window. If you want the bottom of the element to be at the top of the window (truly scrolling to the bottom of the element, but it will be out of the viewport), just scroll to `divBot` instead.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var wHeight = $(window).height(),
    divTop = $('#one').offset().top,
    divHeight = $('#one').outerHeight(),
    divBot = divTop + divHeight;
  
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: (divBot - wHeight)
  }, 2000);
})
```

```css
div {
  height: 200vh;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
#one {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><button>click</button></div>
<div id="one"></div>
<div></div>
```