# scrollIntoView doesn't scroll to bottom when there is an image/file in the container

Tags: reactjs, js-scrollintoview

I have a react app that has a commenting section. Users can comment pdfs, images, excel & csv files. When a user opens up a project I want the container with comments to scroll to the very bottom. The functionality works perfectly if the comments are only text. However, when someone adds any sort of file in, it will no longer scroll all the way to the bottom. It only scroll about 3/4 and the more files added, the less it scrolls.

This is where its called:

```
     componentDidUpdate() {
          this.scrollToBottom()
       }

     scrollToBottom(){
         this.el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
       }
```

This is whats in my render:

```
     <div className="comments-container-parent">
              {this.props.projectComments.map((comment) => {
                return <ProjectComment  editCommentText={this.props.editCommentText} commentId={comment.id} deleteComment={this.props.deleteComment} comment={comment} projectData={this.props.projectData} />

              })}
              <div style={{ float:"left", clear:"both" }}  ref={el => { this.el = el }}></div>
     </div>
```

How can I get the scroll to work properly when files are involved?

Comment: you should be able to get the offset position of the div, then get the bounding rectangle of the div, and add the bottom value of the rectangle to the offset and scroll the window to that y value. Here is another post which gives an example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41559958/scrolling-window-to-the-bottom-of-an-element)

Comment: @RyanWilson thank you for your response. I tried this, and i'm getting a similar result. It looks like when there are only text comment it scrolls to the bottom. but when an image of files is uploaded it doesnt take into account the height of that images/files. So the scrollTop is the container MINUS the height of the images/files.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this recently and the solution was to make sure that there is a container (div or whatever) with a fixed height set. Setting the height dynamically or based on some logic in a useEffect hook doesn't work. The height of the images must be set from the start so that when the list renders, the height of the list doesn't change.